# Regex get specific instance of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a variable amount of strings that are contained in a row separated by spaces.

The last two values before the CRLF are always present and I need to extract the second to last numeric value using Regex.

I originally tried `(.+?[ ]{1,}){6}.+?\r\n` but it could be the 5th or 6 instance I need extracted.

```
66666666     RCA     JOBS               CASH      300,080.47 0000ABCDE\r\n

66666666     RCA     JOBS      182.09   VL          9,755.02 0000FGHIJ\r\n
```

Comment: So you need "0000ABCDE" and "0000FGHIJ"?

Comment: Try [`var res = s.Split().Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().Last();`](https://ideone.com/jNu4ES)

Comment: Try [`(\S+)\s+\S+\r?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cS%2b%29%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=66666666+++++RCA+++++JOBS+++++++++++++++CASH++++++300%2c080.47+0000ABCDE)

Comment: When (what condition) do you want the 5th instance and when do you want the 6th instance?

Answer (score 0):

You could name your groups. This should work `"(.+?[ ]{1,}){5}(?<MyFirstValue>.+?[ ]{1,})(?<MySecondValue>.*)`

```
var regex = new Regex("(.+?[ ]{1,}){5}(?<MyFirstValue>.+?[ ]{1,})(?<MySecondValue>.*)");
var test = @"66666666     RCA     JOBS               CASH      300,080.47 0000ABCDE
66666666     RCA     JOBS      182.09   VL          9,755.02 0000FGHIJ";


Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", 
    regex
        .Matches(test)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups["MyFirstValue"].Value + " " + m.Groups["MySecondValue"].Value)));
```

[Test it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bBewUR)

Comment: Because of the way our code is structured, I need it returned in Group 1.  And to answer your other question, I'm looking to get the 300,080.47 extracted .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following RegEx, if you want the second last Word:

```
\S+(?= \S+\r$)
```

It Works by selecting any non-Space chacacters followed by a Space, Some non-Space characters, a 'return' at the end of line.

**Edit:**

*You must set the `multiline` option for the RegEx.*
**Edit2:**

If you only want the first line you can also use:

```
\S+(?= \S+\r)
```

(without the 'endofline')

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  I only the need the 2nd to last value extracted from the first row which can be in either format.

Comment: Set the 'multiLine' option !